MySQL giving me 4 rows,there should be one,I don't know
I'm  a beginner apprentice. I don't know why my code is returning extra duplicate rows.
Code:
SELECT * 
FROM employees

It returns the list, but repeated multiple times and the first number on the first original answer does not repeat along with the repetitions:
1
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5 and the like..

I don't know what to try. I created the database and everything was running smoothly. All of a sudden, it is sending me these extra rows.

If the DB is actually returning more rows than you expect, then it seems overwhelmingly likely that that is because the database (now) actually contains more rows than you expect.  However, it is also possible that the database is not returning additional rows, but instead your code prints some of them more than once.  To help you distinguish between these possibilities, we need to know exactly how you are performing the query and outputting the result.

You could also consider checking something like select count(*) from employees, which asks the database to tell you how many rows are in the table (according to it).

Ok I did that -count- it returned 17 and it was not that when I created it,I tried uploading a pic but this won't let me upload saying it's too big. I did -desc- too to see table structure too

@JoseSantana,fyi - do not post screenshots , simple copy/paste is all that is required. Perhaps dropping the table and start again may be your best way forward, are there other users of this db that may also be inserting into the table ? . An employee table with a single column is going to be of limited use.

That is happening because there are multiple rows with employee information with name primary key column.
Primary Keys in the employee table should be unique...
how-to-change-primary-key-into-unique-key-when-fks-reference-it
If you don't want to show duplicate data ... use query as follows:
select distinct empno, col1, col2 from employees;

